# What is meant by this *ptr = len

Tags: c++

While reading some code about copy constructors in C++, I found a statement like this `*ptr=len`(where `len` is an `int` type variable and `*ptr` is a `int` type pointer).

What does this mean?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/book/pointers

Comment: you should read a tuto/book on c++, especially pointers

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1):

It is assignment to the value/location pointed to by `ptr`.  To put it another way, we are assigning the value of `len` to the value that `ptr` points to.

For example:

```
// Declare and initialize int variable.
int x = 0;
// Declare pointer-to-int variable, initialize to be pointing at x.
int *xp = &x;

// Assign to the value _pointed to by_ xp, which is x.  In other words,
// assigning to *xp is the same thing as assigning to x.
*xp = 1;

// Will display 1, because x was reassigned through *xp.
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Comment: That is implied by "through."

Answer (score -1):

it means that the **contents** of the ptr variable is not the value of len.

in other words, the value of the variable pointed out by ptr, has the value of len.

```
int foo;
int *a = &foo; // a points to the memory of foo.
int value = 10;
(*a) = value; // changes the value of foo via pointer indirection.
```

now (*a) equals 10.

Comment: aaaand the `delete` :)

Comment: I feel the use of `new` and `auto` here is distracting from what the example is trying to illustrate since OP is presumably an absolute beginner.

Comment: i don't know, I could go old fashioned c++03 style but I felt that explaining in modern c++ is easier in a lot of cases.

Comment: Modern C++ discourages the use of `new` and `delete`. I think it would be easier to just use a pointer to automatic storage (i.e. `int i; int* a = &i; ...`).